PC-lint suppress error within `/* ... */` block comment
I've got a doc comment like:
/**
 * See [datasheet][1] for details.
 *
 * [1]: https://example.com
 */
void my_func(void);

And PC-lint is upset because note 9259: C comment contains '://' sequence [MISRA 2012 Rule 3.1, required]. I want to disable this warning/note.
From the PC-lint manual for e9259:

[9259] C comment contains '://' sequence
Message 9059 reports on cases where a C comment contains what may be a C++ comment, e.g. the sequence ’//’. Because including URLs inside of comments is a common practice, message 9059 is not issued when the
’//’ sequence is immediately preceded by a ’:’ to prevent the message from being issued in cases such as:
/* See http://www.gimpel.com for details */
This message (ie, message 9529) fills the gap by reporting on the instances not reported by 9059.

And the PC-lint manual for e9059:

[9059] C comment contains C++ comment
A C++-style comment was seen inside a C-style comment. This can be confusing.

I've tried appending !e9259 to the offending line, as well as lint !e9259, but they don't work. I can't do something like /*lint !e9259 because PC-lint then complains about /* in a block comment. For the same reason //lint !e9259 won't work. I also can't wrap the doc comment in /*lint -save -e9259*/ and /*lint -restore*/ because that will break doxygen's parsing of the function's doc comment.

So this MISRA rule has the side effect of forbidding URLs in comments?

For Doxygen, a %zwj; HTML entity could be placed between the slashes, like this /&zwj;/. Unfortunately, that would no longer produce a working link, although it would look like a link when printed. Probably more useful for documenting example code fragments that contain comments.

My bad ________

So it's telling you it's not generating a warning? How helpful.

Maybe the root cause is that you are referring to URLs in comments instead of your local project documentation. That code will not stay maintainable when the URL goes poof.

@IanAbbott URLs are explicitly allowed. MISRA already anticipated this problem and therefore let URLs within comments to be a valid exception to rule 3.1. The reason behind the rule is to block "commented-out code" from being present in production builds, nothing else.

@Lundin So perhaps the note message is only informational, not reporting a violation?

@IanAbbott I just dug up more info about this, the original 2012 version of MISRA C didn't have the exception for URLs. It was added in some technical corrigendum. So the problem could simply be an outdated version of PC Lint. If it only supports MISRA C:2012 but none of the TC, then it would have this problem. This is a "Required" rule with capital R so it's not just informal, one has to follow it or do a formal deviation of the rule.

The original MISRA C:2012 release from year 2012 had a hiccup here in regards to URLs. This has since then been fixed in technical corrigendums (TC).
MISRA C:2012 including all TC (aka MISRA C:2023), rule 3.1 has the following exception to the rule:


Uniform resource identifiers, of the form {scheme}://{path}, are permitted within comments.


There is even an explicit example of an URL within comments as an acceptable exception to rule 3.1! So your code is MISRA compliant in this regard.
The purpose of rule 3.1 is to block "commented-out code" from being present in production builds, nothing else. And so a :// sequence is fine, a  // C99 comment is not.
So either PC Lint is broken or you are using an old version which isn't updated to the current MISRA C. Both you and PC Lint should be using MISRA C:2023 which is the same document as MISRA C:2012 but with all technical corrigendums included.

9059 does ignore URLs. 9259 reintroduces it. Presumably because it's possible it silence 9259.

As @Lundin has correctly pointed out, the original MISRA C:2012 would cause this to be triggered by Rule 3.1 - this was an unintentional consequence of the Rule.
This was corrected by section 3.1.3 of MISRA C:2012 Amendment 4 (March 2023) (free download available) which has been integrated as part of MISRA C:2023.
If you are using a tool that is still reporting this as a violation, you have two options:

Upgrade or replace your tool
Create a project deviation, citing AMD4 as the justification

See profile for my affiliation!
